# Call to member function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code and I'm trying to understand and find a solution for this error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Tank_auth::$users

Filename: libraries/Tank_auth.php

Line Number: 188

Fatal error: Call to a member function UpdateProfileInfo() on a non-object in /home/xtremer/public_html/kowmanager/application/libraries/Tank_auth.php on line 188
```

Tank Auth Controller: http://pastebin.com/iRj11hgR
Tank Auth Model: http://pastebin.com/qhNK5Whz
Tank Auth Library: http://pastebin.com/RVxdzhUa

Edit: Thanks to Marc he was able to find the problem but I do have a new issue oddly.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: userID

Filename: libraries/Tank_auth.php

Line Number: 188
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xtremer/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 671
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xtremer/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 543
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `application/libraries/Tank_auth.php` has 188 lines??

Comment: There is no $users in any of the code samples you've pasted, and none of the code samples have a line 188. You're holding out on us...

Comment: I was only trying to give the relevant code so it didn't detear anyone anyway from helping out.

Comment: I updated all the links to include the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly relevant:

line 187: `$this->ci->users`
line 188: `$this->users->UpdateProfileInfo(...);`

forgot a `->ci` in Tank Auth Library?

Comment: Well that solved one thing. Funny thing is I get one issue fixed and another is uncovered. My new error is in my post.

Comment: PHP array keys are case sensitive. maybe it's `user_id` or `userid`  and not `userID?` hard to say. The headers errors/warning should go away once you fix the undefined index warning.

Comment: Well I changed $this->ci->users->UpdateProfileInfo($userInfo['userID'],$userInfo['first_name'],$userInfo['last_name']);  to this $this->ci->users->UpdateProfileInfo($userInfo['user_id'],$userInfo['first_name'],$userInfo['last_name']);   And still got the same errror.

Comment: This is so frustrating and yet I'm so close.

Comment: try doing `var_dump($userInfo)` and see what's in there, rather than just guessing at key names.

Comment: array(2) { ["first_name"]=> NULL ["last_name"]=> NULL }

Comment: That was on the library page though.

Comment: If you can send me an email and I'll show you the live version. (xtremer360@yahoo.com)

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that your tank_auth/users.php model is not loading, or there is a naming conflict somewhere.  What does your $autoload array look like?

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','template','asset','session');